# usb sniffing with wireshark

Tags: usb, wireshark, usb-flash-drive

at the moment I am using usbmon to sniff usb. for better understandability I want to use wireshark. I've used wireshark before for sniffing ethernet packets. But what to capture to sniff USB Packets ? I meant I need to start by selecting which interface to capture in wireshark. but what wold I select there for usb ?

Comment: From what I can tell, this is not currently possible with wireshark on windows.

Comment: Wireshark can only sniff USB on Linux.  The easiest way to sniff packets is to use vmware.  http://vusb-analyzer.sourceforge.net/tutorial.html

Answer (score 11):

Grab newest wireshark.
Use lsusb **before and after plugin in device** so You know which usb bus its plugged into.

type in terminal:

```
su -c "modprobe usbmon" && su -c "wireshark"
```

(First load kernel module that allow for usb sniffing for root, second load wireshark as root)

Than select `usbmonX`, where `X` stand for usb bus number (`lsusb` show those numbers).

After than you still need to filter packets for device / vendor id, or something else device specific, as wireshark will show all packets from all devices plugged into that bus. (Again `lsusb` before/after plugging you device will help).

Comment: Running wireshark as root can be dangerous, better to set up additional wireshark user. It's done automatically on standard distributions like Fedora and Ubuntu. So installing wireshark with package manager would be the easiest solution, anyway you may come across problems with permissions like 'Can't open USB bus file /sys/kernel/debug/usb/usbmon/2t: Permission denied' this can be easily solved by setting few permissions to files. Manual here: http://ludovicrousseau.blogspot.com/2014/10/ccid-usb-spy-using-wireshark.html

Answer (score 3):

Have you taken a look at [the documentation for that](http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/USB) on the Wireshark website?

> In libpcap 1.0.x, the devices for capturing on USB have the name usbn, where n is the number of the bus. In libpcap 1.1.0 and later, they have the name usbmonn.

Comment: Sorry But I still didn't understand. I want to listen to the conversation with My Pen Drive, or with my USB Keyboard. There are 3 options to start capturing etc0, ppp0, lo, then how can I get the USB Conversation

Comment: Upgrade to the latest version of libpcap (and/or probably your Linux distribution), and then use Wireshark to capture on the interfaces with names similar to "usbmon1".

Answer (score 0):

a quick notice since I just started using  wireshark to sniff usb packets on linux. as I understand you need usbmon module loaded (which if you are using it should be). Additionally I seem to recall that while wireshark can be setup to let non root users sniff ethernet packets, some limitation required root access for usb packs (at least at the time of writting).
Similar to what others have said, on my system, Ubuntu 12.10, the usb interfaces have names like "usbmon1 USB bus number 1" and so forth.
(you might look at  http://biot.com/blog/usb-sniffing-on-linux)
the link listed has an image showing a filter which can be used to select only traffic to from a device number (from lsusb).

I hope thats helpful

Answer (score 0):

@przemo_li You want to filter by device address to see the communication from both the host and the device.  The filter for that is `usb.device_address ==`.